# cd into /Contents/ in Automator

Tags: bash, macos, automator

I've got my Automator project, and what I want to do is `cd` (change directory) into "itself" (as if you'd click `Show Package Contents`). How may I do that?

From there, I can create folders, create files, etc., I've got that part, however I don't know how to change directory into the `Contents` of my .app.

Comment: you have to unpack the .app file to get access to all it's files and directories

Comment: @0.sh Yeah, I know, but what's the code I should give it before exporting it? I know I'm meant to run the App afterwards, but what should I do beforehand?